# LockScreen Widget reload every minute

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget

I'm currently developing a world clock LockScreen widget, which is supposed to display current time of the selected city.

The code I'm using to reload it every minute is the following:

```
func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<ThemeEntry>) -> ()) {

        var entries: [ThemeEntry] = []

        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 60 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = ThemeEntry(date: entryDate, configuration: configuration, theme: ThemeEntity(index: hourOffset))
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
```

It works as expected, meaning 0..<60 does it's job and reloads my widget every minute, but the problem is at some point (after a couple of hours) it stops reloading and freezes.
I've found a couple of apps on AppStore which have the same functionality and their widgets with world time work like charm, so I suppose it's possible to achieve.

What could be the solution?